# div expand and collapse is not working in my php code

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my php page i have these following code:-

```
 <?php
     include ('dbConnect/dbConnect.php');
     $query = "Select * from RitualType";
     $queryResult = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
?>
<!--    <div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-110-6-1" >--><br/>
<div class="row-fluid" style="">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="" style="position: fixed; left: 50pt; width:254px;height:50px; top: 87px; z-index: 99999999;" >
        <div class="textwidget" ><?php $i = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)) {
                ?><div id="SpanHoma">
                     <span class=""  style="color: red;font-size: 14px;"><strong><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></strong></span>
                     <div class="textwidget" id="RitualsGroup" style="display:none;">
                     <?php
                          $query1 = "Select * from Rituals where RitualTypeId=" . $row['Id'];
                          $queryResult1 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query1);
                     ?>  
                     <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult1)) { ?>
                        <div class="Homas" > <?php echo "<a style='color: #000000;' href='#" . $row1['Id'] . "'>" ?>
                            <i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> <span class="what-we-offer" style="color: #000000;"> 
        <?php echo $row1['Name'] ?> </span><?php echo '</a>'; ?><br />
            </div><?php $i++;
        } ?>
        </div></div><?php } ?>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Where `RitualType` is Heading and Rituals are the contents.
I need to make the div expand and collapsible. Right Now the page is like this

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

When i click A then the contents of A is getting displayed like

```
A
  a 
  b
  c
B
C
D
E
```

But when i click B the div is not getting expanded. It only Works for A. I want the particular div to open when i click the Main Heading.

`Javascript` Code to `toggle`is shown below

```
 $(function () {

      $("#SpanHoma").on("click", function () {

           $("#RitualsGroup").toggle();
      });
      $('.RitualsGroup').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try like this (convert id to class in `html` and change javascript code like below):-

```
$(function () { 
   $(".SpanHoma").on("click", function () {
      $(this).find(".RitualsGroup").toggle(); // this will check which one is clicked currently
   }); 
});
```

```js
$(function () { 
       $(".SpanHoma").on("click", function () {
          $(this).find(".RitualsGroup").toggle(); // this will check which one is clicked currently
       }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "SpanHoma">
  <span>A</span>
  <div class= "RitualsGroup" style = "display:none;">
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
   </div>
</div>

<div class= "SpanHoma">
  <span>B</span>
  <div class= "RitualsGroup" style = "display:none;">
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of you are giving same id for multiple div. try this:

change this:

```
<div id="SpanHoma">
```

to

```
<div class="SpanHoma">
```

and

```
<div class="textwidget" id="RitualsGroup" style="display:none;">
```

to

```
<div class="textwidget RitualsGroup" style="display:none;">
```

in jquery:

```
 $(function () {

                $(".SpanHoma").on("click", function () {

                    $(this).find(".RitualsGroup").toggle();
                });

            });
```

Comment: Now my first `div` is also not getting expanded.

Comment: Have you change id to class? I have check this solution . It must work.

Comment: pls post your updated code. Also check your console that you are not getting error